# error '-2147217887(80040e21) odbc driver doesnt support requested properties'

Tags: sql-server, vb6, odbc

**Hi, i've a problem to load data from SQL in my MSHFlexGrid. This is my code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim rs As Recordset

Private Sub btnEmpieza_Click()
rs.Open "SELECT CorridaVigenciaEncabezado.CVE_Titulo, CorridaVigenciaEncabezado.CVE_Mail " _
    & "FROM CorridaVigenciaEncabezado INNER JOIN Usuarios " _
    & "ON CorridaVigenciaEncabezado.USU_IdSolicitado = Usuarios.Codigo " _
    & "INNER JOIN Solicitud on CorridaVigenciaEncabezado.CVE_Titulo = Solicitud.ANTITSOL " _
    & "WHERE Solicitud.ANDNICLI =19002108 ", Cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly
    Grilla
    rs.Close
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
Set rs = New Recordset
rs.CursorLocation = adUseServer
End Sub

Private Sub Estructura()
    GrillaDatos.Cols = 2
    GrillaDatos.TextMatrix(0, 1) = "Título"
    GrillaDatos.TextMatrix(0, 2) = "Mail"
    GrillaDatos.ColWidth(0) = 1000
    GrillaDatos.ColWidth(1) = 1000
    GrillaDatos.ColAlignment(0) = 4
    GrillaDatos.ColAlignment(1) = 4
End Sub

Private Sub Grilla()
    Dim i As Integer
    GrillaDatos.Clear
    Estructura
    GrillaDatos.Rows = rs.RecordCount + 1
    i = 1
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do While rs.EOF = False
        i = i + 1
        GrillaDatos.TextMatrix(i, 0) = rs!CVE_Titulo
        GrillaDatos.TextMatrix(i, 1) = rs!CVE_Mail
        rs.MoveNext
        i = i + 1
    Loop
rs.Close
End Sub
```

But when i press button, it shows the next error:

```
runtime error Run time error'-2147217887(80040e21) odbc driver doesnt support requested properties.
```

In this line:

[image]

```
rs.Open "SELECT CorridaVigenciaEncabezado.CVE_Titulo, CorridaVigenciaEncabezado.CVE_Mail " _
        & "FROM CorridaVigenciaEncabezado INNER JOIN Usuarios " _
        & "ON CorridaVigenciaEncabezado.USU_IdSolicitado = Usuarios.Codigo " _
        & "INNER JOIN Solicitud on CorridaVigenciaEncabezado.CVE_Titulo = Solicitud.ANTITSOL " _
        & "WHERE Solicitud.ANDNICLI =19002108 ", Cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly
```

So, can anyone tells me what's wrong with my code? 'cause i don't understand what's wrong. i had readed about this problem and i don't know to do

Comment: Since the problem is an ODBC error I edited the title of the question to fit better. The use of MSHFlexGrid seems unrelated?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the definition of `Cn` and how it is setup - is it a connection string, or an ADODB.Connection object? Seems the problem might be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case the ODBC driver doesn't support the CursorType, try changing the CursorType in the `Open` method of the Recordset object.

You can try with `adOpenStatic` or `adOpenUnspecified`.

```
..., Cn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
```